# Need to save Django server log

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi I am making an app on django,where I have a server running continuously.I need to save all the log which I see on terminal of django server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Django's logging facilities. Then you can choose where to log your message (i.e. to a file, to the console, by e-mail). Django has good built-in logging support (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/). You can configure the logging in your `settings.py` like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'your_app_name': { # for your app
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': { # for all django-internal messages
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Then you can log anything using `logging.log('message')`